# ASP.net MVC4 Hide View Source HTML , Javascript code

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html

I am using ASP.net MVC4 .

I want to hide or not to display any HTML & javascript code similar as in Lightswitch HTML client in Right Click View Source , instead of disabling Right click.

For example if you run any Durundal Application or Light Switch HTML client , Right Click View Source does not show any HTML or JavaScript Code except Layout , I am looking for same behavior

How can I achieve that.

Comment: What you do with IE menu View->Source? , Firefox/Chrome console and Fiddler/FireBug? You uninstall the browser to prevent?

Answer (score 1):

unlike server-side scripts, you **can't** hide your html / css / javascript.

the only thing you can is to [obfuscate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript) stuff (make your html/css/javascript less readable and more complicated to understand).

client-side code & markup will always be available for the client. on every http request the browser actually downloads the files and reads them locally.

hope that helps.

Comment: But if you run any Durundal Application or Light Switch HTML client , Right Click View Source does not show any HTML or Javascript Code except Layout , I am looking for same behavioour

Comment: @ineffablep are you sure I dont see that sources in fiddler? :)